# Cannot center menu bar with CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap, I cannot figure out what I need to center "MiDs" element so that it lines up with the rest but the black goes off the edges like it currently is.

Comment: You want to center the entire black bar or just line up the next on the left side of the content below it?

Comment: Everything within the black bar. The width of the rest of the page, but to keep the black bar extended on both sides.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you need to center element .container-fluid. If so, edit style as follows:

```
.container-fluid {
...
/* min-width: 940px; remove this line */
width: 940px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this

`margin: 0px 50% -40px 50%;`

to

`.brand`

Comment: That's kind of what I was looking for, but I want everything in the black bar to fit in the same width as the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is create a div within the black bar that's the same width as the rest of the page, and center that.  If you put MiDs in that, it will line up with the rest of the page.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a million ways to skin this cat, but what I would do is add an extra class to the div that has your link in it (it already has `container-fluid` as a class).

You need a class that overrides container-fluid's margins because you need auto margins. Guess which class does that? Wrap! So add `wrap` to that div and the entire thing will be aligned with your content. The text is not centered within yet; it is on the left of the now-centered div.

I didn't dig much deeper than that in terms of markup, but I suspect you won't need your old ancestor `wrap` element anymore; it was probably there because it seemed like the place to put it (wrapping up stuff you wanted in there!) but I believe it just needed to be more deeply nested in order to escape the fixed positioning of the top bar.

Did you still need to center the text itself? You'll need to unfloat the anchor and then adjust the padding accordingly since it gets moved into the document flow.

Answer (score 0):

I think what I was asking for in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789730/how-do-i-extend-a-div-or-background-past-the-horizontal-page-boundaries-witho) <-check the fiddle there to see

For the black div:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

That will make it extend to the edges of the browser regardless of how wide it gets.

Then make another div, and `margin-left:` the width of the side menu, so it pushes "MiDs" and whatever other content you put in there to the right of the side menu.

If you want it centered, set a width to it and use `margin: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<span><a class="brand" href="/index.php">MiDs</a></span>
---------
-------
------
</div>

/*css*/

.container-fluid span {
display:block;
width:100px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.topbar h3 a, .topbar .brand {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 1;
  padding: 8px 20px 12px;
}
```

remove float ?